# XmlAccessType.FIELD vs XmlAccessType.PROPERTY

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

**This is my below JAXB Binding class .**

```
Request Sample :    <request cust="1222"/>

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class CustAcct {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String cust;

    public String getCust() {
        return cust;
    }

    public void setCust(String cust) {
        this.cust = cust;
    }

    public CustAcct() {

        super();
    }
}
```

**when i used the Property (XmlAccessType.FIELD) everything is working fine , but i tried the above JAXB class using @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY) . Its giving the below exception .**

Could anybiody please tell me why i am getting the Exception when used with XmlAccessType.PROPERTY

```
Class has two properties of the same name "cust"
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at public java.lang.String de.vogella.jersey.first.CustAcct.getCust()
                at de.vogella.jersey.first.CustAcct
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at private java.lang.String de.vogella.jersey.first.CustAcct.cust
                at de.vogella.jersey.first.CustAcct

        at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:113)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:454)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:138)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:166)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:70)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:279)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:86)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1357)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1289)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1239)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1229)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:497)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:684)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
```

Comment: The following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Great explanation in that website . Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add @`XmlAttribute` to `public String getCust()` method as the access type is PROPERTY.